# Python Importing Functions

Tags: python, import

If I have a function defined in my code lets call foo(), and I use the following code:

```
from mod1 import *
```

With mod1 containing a function also with the same name of foo() and call the foo() function, will this override my original definition of the function when it evaluates it?

Comment: Is the function definition before or after the import?

Comment: (In general, this is why it's a good idea to avoid `import *`)

Comment: It's defined before the import, and yes this is just an exercise for one of my classes so I understand it is typically poor form

Comment: -1. Why can't you just test this yourself with some output, as a few of the answers did for you?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it will.

you would need to either rename you `foo()` function you have built **OR** change your module input to read 
`import mod1` and subsequently define any use of the `foo()` function from `mod1` to `mod1.foo()`

Answer (score 3):

Depends on where the function is:

```
def foo():
    pass

from mod1 import *

foo() # here foo comes from mod1

# ------- 
# another interesting case

def foo():
    from mod1 import *
    foo() # this will also call foo from mod1
foo()     # but this one is still the foo defined above.     

# ---------
# The opposite 

from mod1 import *

def foo():
    pass

foo() # here foo is the one defined above
```

Anyway, `from module import *` is considered a VERY bad and error-prone practice. It is a kind of `using namespace std;`-like thing in C++. Avoid it as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I get the following:

file mod1.py contains

```
def foo():
    print "hello foo"
```

and then i start python interpreter and do the following:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print "hello world"
... 
>>> from mod1 import *
>>> foo()
hello foo
>>>
```

So yes, it would override.

Unless you then do, a new

```
def foo():
    print "new foo"
```

In which case it would print "new foo"

Answer (score 1):

### a.py

```
def foo():
    print 'Hello A'
```

### Test

```
>>> def foo():
...     print 'Hello 1'
... 
>>> foo()
Hello 1
>>> from a import *
>>> foo()
Hello A
>>> def foo():
...     print 'Hello 2'
... 
>>> foo()
Hello 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relative order of the function definition and the `import` statement. Whichever is executed second will override the first.